# Depth-first search, Recursion, For loops, and Return

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, return, depth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a DFS algorithm to figure out if there is a path between a `start` node and a `target` node. Here's the code I have so far:

```
# Depth-first search
def find_path2(s, t):
    s.visited = True

    if s.data == t.data:
        return True

    for node in s.neighbors:
        if not node.visited:
            return find_path2(graph, node, t)


node_0 = Node(0)
node_1 = Node(1)
node_2 = Node(2)
node_3 = Node(3)
node_4 = Node(4)
node_5 = Node(5)
node_6 = Node(6)

node_0.neighbors = [node_1]
node_1.neighbors = [node_2]
node_2.neighbors = [node_3, node_0]
node_3.neighbors = [node_2]
node_4.neighbros = [node_6]
node_5.neighbros = [node_4]
node_6.neighbors = [node_5]

start = node_2
target = node_0


if find_path2(start, target):
    print("There is a path between {} and {}".format(start.data, target.data))
else:
    print("There is no path between {} and {}".format(start.data, target.data))
```

node_2 has both node_3 and node_0 as neighbors and so it should print that there is a path between them. I understand that the return statement is exiting the for loop during the first execution because a return statement exits the function and therefore never visits node_0.

My question is, what is the most elegant way to go about that? Thank you!

Comment: Does this code work as expected, or not? DFS pseudocode on Wikipedia is straightforward, IMO. I think this code errors at `find_path2(my_graph, node, t)` because `my_graph` does not exist and there are only 2 parameters to be passed

Comment: There's many errors in the code but issue you're describing likely happens because you're considering only one of the neighbours in `find_path2`. You could try replacing the `for` loop with something like `return any(find_path2(node, t) for node in s.neighbors if not node.visited)`.

Comment: the `my_graph` was an old parameter that I forgot it but when I was testing I had deleted it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure you only return from the loop over the neighbours if you've found the node you're looking for:

```
def find_path2(s, t):
    s.visited = True

    if s.data == t.data:
        return True

    for node in s.neighbors:
        if not node.visited:
            if find_path2(node, t):
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.